How to round vertices of subdivided mesh?
I am new to blender and I am trying to model an island. Currently I am just trying to get ideas for a layout and doing some UV editing. I have these faces mapped to green and white colors and I want to know if I can smooth these vertices to not be so sharp.

I am not sure on the correct terminology for something like this so I have been having difficulty finding solutions that may already be out there.
Here is another reference in case there are better approaches to achieving this

Since I am new to this I am having trouble retaining info that is most relevant to what I am trying to achieve so if there are any good references out there for learning as well that would also be helpful.

Why don't you use one material only, and an image texture as mask to separate yellow from green, or simply paint your yellow and green on an image texture?

That is what I am doing. I am going to make this more complex like making the mountains gray, add some dirt patches and other details. But when selecting faces I think I am going to still have this issue unless there is something I am missing

That is not what you are doing, you are using the topology to assign a different material to each face, unless you have a good reason to do that, it's generally not a good way to give different colors to your object, the best is to give one material and either use mask to separate the areas or directly paint one image texture for the whole area

If you want to assign several colors to your objects, rather than assigning a different material per face, it's much more convenient to assign one material to the whole object and use the texture painting to color the surface:

If one of your color is supposed to have a different shader (for example here the green is metallic and the cream is not), then mix 2 shaders with a b&w image texture as factor:

